ContextDB Disposed Before Background task finish
I am trying to build a Http API By C#. After returning the HTTP Response, I need to do some works and then update the database in the background.
However, I guess the DBContext instance is disposed automatically after the returning the API response, therefore, this error shows up:

"System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application"

Here is my Code:
public async Task<DBmodel> GetAttachmentsListById(Guid Id, bool RequestSync)
{
    var target = await Repository.GetDBmodelById(Id);
    if (target != null)
    {
        if (RequestSync)
        {
            SyncAttachment(target);
        }
        if (target != null)
        {
            
            return DBmodel
        }
    }
    
    return null!;
}

public void SyncAttachment(DBmodel target)
{
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    var executeScope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
    var ServiceProvider = executeScope.ServiceProvider;
    var repository = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Repository>();
    Action a = async () =>
    {
        ExternalClient Client = new ExternalClient();
        var ExternalResult = await //Get External Information
        if (//NeedUpdate)
        {
            foreach (var x in ExternalResult )
            {
                    var model = new DBmodel;
                    model = ExternalResult;
                    await repository.UpDateDBmodel(att);//Exception Occurs Here
            }
        }
    };
    Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(a);
    task1.ContinueWith( c =>
    {
        executeScope.Dispose();
    });
}


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio just firing off a task is not enough as you need a new scope and DbContext. Also never use Task.StartNew and ContinueWith https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html if you really needed this you would use Task.Run instead.

I already have a background service scheduled hourly, but however, I still want to update  the database one more time when I get a sync request, that's why I need a background task. Besides, If I don't use continue with, how can I disposed the executescope

See those docs: create a new background service that waits on a queue of tasks to run.

You are not waiting for the task to finish.
Because of this, your executeScope will be disposed which in turn disposes of your context.
You could also just get your scope and all inside your Action. This will avoid this problem.
